# LICENSE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED exception for Customer Community Plus Login even though more than 25k+ licenses are remaining

Tags: customer-community, licenses, user-management, experience-cloud, customer-community-plus

I'm getting `Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: LICENSE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, License Limit Exceeded - Customer Community Plus Login: []` but there are more than 25k licenses remaining for "Customer Community Plus Login" user license
[image: Licenses]

[image: Exception Screen]

Comment: Seems like something to raise a case with Salesforce about (unless this is actually about licensing of an app exchange package with a misleading error message)?

Comment: We do not assign any app license to community users.
Created a case with Salesforce.

Comment: Does it show the same error when another system admin user tried to "enable customer user"? Also, is the count more than 50k when you run `SELECT count(id),ownerid from account where IsPersonAccount=true `

Comment: Yes, same error irrespective of who is enabling the customer user. Neither do we have "Person Account" enabled in org. This is happening in a full copy sandbox. It's a new development stuck in UAT testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is misleading.
It doesn't necessarily relate to the specified license, it can relate to other licenses being provisioned at that time for that user e.g. feature licenses.

Comment: It was related to the knowledge license. We were assigning knowledge license (meant for standard users) to community users.